# JS - Passing data to front-end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, json

The task: *We have some dynamically generated data on the backend that should be passed to the front-end as fast as possible*

The question is: **How to pass data from back-end to front-end JS in faster but more efficient and maintainable way**

---

### Straightforward solution

Here's an example of sending data right into html (template-part.php):

```
<body>
<!-- HTML GOES HERE -->

<script> const someDataJSON = <?= json_encode($someBackEndData); ?></script>
<script src="/path/to/script/that/rely/on/someDataJSONObject.js"></script>
</body>
```

Assuming that `$someBackEndData` is a valid json-serialization-ready array of data. We pass it with template so what happens here is we send JSON with our template to the client. Once template is rendered by browser someDataJSON is available **globaly** to all the scripts.

Pros/Cons:

- + *The fastest way to send json data to front-end known to me*
- + *No additional requests*
- + *Loaded once HTML page is rendered by browser*
- - *Pollutes global scope*
- - *Harder to maintain:* There're could be a lot of other template parts as well as more than 1 variable that's set this way. It can be hard to track where the JSON object is initialized

---

### But do we really need that speed?

JS frameworks usually take time to load its core and compile expressions and templates (AngularJS with its $compile, etc.). So there's no need in the data loaded that fast as front-end app will still need some time to boot. Before that: *there's no one who can process our loaded data*

---

### Load via additional request at the very beginning of the app

template-example.php:

```
<!-- template body here -->

<script src="/path/to/webpack/parseljs/rollup/whatever/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

input-for-bundler.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';

// declare variable to hold our data
const JSONdata = [];

// fetch our data
fetch('/path/to/jsondata/')
    .then(data => JSONdata = data.json())

angular.module(/*......... APPLICATION CODE
```

Pros/Cons:

- + *Data is loaded inside the script:* It's possible to track and manage the source of data
- - *Additional ajax request*
- - *Pollutes global scope*

We can get rid of global scope pollution by making our app lazy loaded:

```
fetch('/path/to/jsondata/')
    .then(data => {
        const JSON = data.json();

        angular.module('ModuleName', [...])
            .constant('jsonData', JSON)
            /* application code */
    });
```

The possible downside here:

- - *Increased loading speed for the whole app as it will be executed only in `then` statement*
- - *App **will not load** if promise fails** (Actually it can be worked around by initing our app inside `.finally()` block of the promise and that's just implementation details)

Will be glad to hear your suggestions as well as constructive criticism.

Comment: What are the Pros/Cons if I use cookies? Is it a good solution?

Comment: A best practice would be to initially load the minimal front-end logic & data needed by your users. Then you may load complementary logic (dynamic component loading) and data as needed.

Comment: @FredG Definitely! But the question is all about ways of loading that data for user.

Comment: @VadZelenin, hard to answer that question globally, it actually depends on you needs. As far as I know, the fastest way to dispatch your data would be to rely only on your backend layer (eg. construct your html page with php). Then you could rely upon the alternatives you mentionned. Could be worth to lazy load js modules & chunks of data to speed up everything. A more precise answer definitively need a deeper analysis of your project.